# Custom Welcome and Finished page with stretched image in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have created an image that I want to appear over whole Welcome and Finished pages of the installer, with only the bottom buttons showing.

The Welcome wizard page should be like:

[image]

The Finished page like:

[image]

I'm getting

[image]

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, note that the Welcome page is disabled by default since [Inno Setup 5.5.7](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.5.7). If you really want it, you have to enable it using [`DisableWelcomePage=no`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablewelcomepage).

To display images only on the pages, you need to do:

- Stretch `WizardBitmapImage` (Welcome) and `WizardBitmapImage2` (Finished) over their respective parent pages.
- Hide the other components, mainly the labels.
- Make sure that the installer never needs to restart the machine, otherwise you get a restart prompt over the image.
- Make sure you do not have any `postinstall` entries in the `[Run]` section, for the same reason.
- The code is designed for `WizardStyle=classic`. For `modern` style it needs to be adjusted.

```pascal
[Setup]
DisableWelcomePage=no
WizardImageFile=godfather.bmp

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { Welcome page }
  { Hide the labels }
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;
  { Stretch image over whole page }
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width :=
    WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Parent.Width;

  { Finished page }
  { Hide the labels }
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Visible := False;
  { Stretch image over whole page }
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Width :=
    WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Parent.Width;
end;
```

[image: Finished page with stretched image]

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all the help :)