# How to make Inno Setup RunList checklist box transparent?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

My installer has a custom finish page with an image on it. I referred this [Custom Welcome and Finished page with stretched image in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705492/custom-welcome-and-finished-page-with-stretched-image-in-inno-setup) solution for it. But the issue is with the check box at finish page, it is coming on top of the finish page image with a white background. If I removed `postinstall` flag, then it will automatically launch my app. But I want the user to be able to choose like how checkbox does. So is there any way to transparent the check box launch message on top of my image? Would `TNewCheckBox` help here?

```
[Run]
Filename: "app\My program.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram}"; #
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard Inno Setup, I do not think you can make `WizardForm.RunList` (`TNewCheckListBox`) transparent. But as the simple `TNewCheckBox` is transparent, you can replace the `WizardForm.RunList` with `TNewCheckBox` (or more of them, if needed – not covered by the code below).

```pascal
[Code]
procedure RunCheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.RunList.Checked[0] := TNewCheckBox(Sender).Checked;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  RunCheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    if (not WizardForm.RunList.Visible) or
       (WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count < 1) then
    begin
      Log('No items to run');
    end
      else
    if WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count > 1 then
    begin
      Log('More than one item to run, ' +
          'keeping the standard non-transparent run list');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Replacing the one item in the run list ' +
          'with a simple transparent checkbox');
      RunCheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
      RunCheckBox.Parent := WizardForm.RunList.Parent;
      RunCheckBox.Left := WizardForm.RunList.Left + ScaleX(4);
      RunCheckBox.Top := WizardForm.RunList.Top + ScaleY(4);
      RunCheckBox.Width := WizardForm.RunList.Width;
      RunCheckBox.Height := ScaleY(RunCheckBox.Height);
      RunCheckBox.Checked := WizardForm.RunList.Checked[0];
      RunCheckBox.Caption := WizardForm.RunList.ItemCaption[0];
      RunCheckBox.OnClick := @RunCheckBoxClick;
      WizardForm.RunList.Visible := False;
    end
  end; 
end;
```

[image]